# Calculating predictions and confidence intervals from a negative binomial distribution

Tags: r, confidence-interval, negative-binomial-distribution, offset

I'm trying to use R's `glm.nb` to calculate predictions and confidence intervals.
When I'm using linear models after training a model, e.g., using:

```
model <- lm(y ~ x)
```

I can get predictions and CIs using:

```
pred <- predict(model, new_x, se.fit=T, interval="prediction", level=0.95)
CI.upper <- pred$fit[2]
    CI.lower <- pred$fit[3]
```

Now I'm using:

```
nb_model <- glm.nb(z ~ x + offset(y))
nb_pred <- predict(nb_model, new_data=data.frame(x=X, y=Y), type="response", se.fit=T)
```

My questions are:

1. How do I get the CI from nb_pred? e.g., the equivalent of `pred$fit[2]` and `pred$fit[3]`
2. The predict function seems to ignore Y - I get the same value from predict with and without providing y=Y. I don't understand why the model seems to ignore the offset variable.

Comment: Are you sure that offset(y) works with glm.nb?  This could why predict isnt working.

Comment: http://twri.tamu.edu/bret/BretWebSiteDocs/GLMCI.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your new data.frame looks like, but you need to make sure they have the same variable names as the variables in your model.
So in your model, your variable names are y and x.
Then 
new = data.frame(X,Y) 
       colnames(new) = c("x","y")
nb_pred <- predict(nb_model, new_data=new, type="response", se.fit=T)